# How to split a long org file into separate org files?

Tags: org-mode, files

I've an huge org file `HUGE.org` with this structure:

```
* ID-HEAD-1 Title1 :TAG:
bla bla bla

* ID-HEAD-2 Title2 :TAG:
bla bla bla

...

* ID-HEAD-N TitleN :TAG:
bla bla bla
```

and I want to split `HUGE.org` into:

```
ID-HEAD-1.org
ID-HEAD-2.org
...
ID-HEAD-N.org
```

where the content of each `ID-HEAD-i.org` is:

```
* ID-HEAD-i Titlei :TAG:
bla bla bla
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Clarification: you mean you want to create N new files, each of which contains the sequentially numbered top-level header and its contents?

Comment: Yes, i want N new files!

Answer (score 7):

I use a function of my own. It moves a subtree to a new org file, and replaces it with a link to this new file. Specify the name of the file through the parameter or interactively at the prompt.

```lisp
(defun org-move-tree (filename)
  "move the sub-tree which contains the point to a file,
and replace it with a link to the newly created file"
  (interactive "F")
  (org-mark-subtree)
  (let
      ((name (buffer-substring (region-beginning)
                               (save-excursion (end-of-line) (point))))
       (xxx (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
    (setq name (replace-regexp-in-string "^[*]+ *" "" name))
    (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (insert (format "[[file:%s][%s]]\n" filename name))
    (find-file-other-window filename)
    (insert xxx)
    (save-buffer)))

(provide 'org-move-tree)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the previous answer as is but I had to tweak it a bit to make it work as I would expect. I think this version might be slightly safer too because it should handle tags correctly.

```lisp
(defun y/org-move-tree (buffer-file-name)
  "move the sub-tree which contains the point to a file,
and replace it with a link to the newly created file"
  (interactive "F")
  (org-mark-subtree)
  (let*
      ((title    (car (last (org-get-outline-path t))))
       (dir      (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))
       (filename (concat dir title ".org"))
       (content  (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
    (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (insert (format "** [[file:%s][%s]]\n" filename title))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert content)
      (write-file filename))))
```